# Plot two histograms on the same graph and have their columns sum to 100

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, histogram, normalize

I have two sets of different sizes that I'd like to plot on the same histogram. However, since one set has ~330,000 values and the other has about ~16,000 values, their frequency histograms are hard to compare. I'd like to plot a histogram comparing the two sets such that the y-axis is the % of occurrences in that bin. My code below gets close to this, except that rather than having the individual bin values sum to 1.0, the integral of the histogram sums to 1.0 (this is because of the normed=True parameter).

How can I achieve my goal? I've already tried manually calculating the % frequency and using plt.bar() but rather than overlaying the plots, the plots are compared side by side. I want to keep the effect of having the alpha=0.5

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

if plt.get_fignums():
    plt.close('all')

electric = pd.read_csv('electric.tsv', sep='\t')
gas = pd.read_csv('gas.tsv', sep='\t')

electric_df = pd.DataFrame(electric)
gas_df = pd.DataFrame(ngma_nonheat)

electric = electric_df['avg_daily']*30
gas = gas_df['avg_daily']*30


## Create a plot for NGMA gas usage
plt.figure("Usage Comparison")

weights_electric = np.ones_like(electric)/float(len(electric))
weights_gas = np.ones_like(gas)/float(len(gas))

bins=np.linspace(0, 200, num=50)

n, bins, rectangles = plt.hist(electric, bins, alpha=0.5, label='electric usage', normed=True, weights=weights_electric)
plt.hist(gas, bins, alpha=0.5, label='gas usage', normed=True, weights=weights_gas)

plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.xlabel('Average 30 day use in therms')
plt.ylabel('% of customers')
plt.title('NGMA Customer Usage Comparison')
plt.show()
```

Comment: If you're using `weights`, you can leave out `normed` in this case.  If you'd like things to sum to 100 instead of 1, multiply the weights by 100.  By leaving out `normed`/`density`, and using the correct `weights`, you'll get scaled bin counts instead of having the values integrate to 1.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It sounds like you don't want the `normed`/`density` kwarg in this case.  You're already using `weights`.  If you multiply your weights by 100 and leave out the `normed=True` option, you should get exactly what you had in mind.

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)

x = np.random.normal(5, 2, 10000)
y = np.random.normal(2, 1, 3000000)

xweights = 100 * np.ones_like(x) / x.size
yweights = 100 * np.ones_like(y) / y.size

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hist(x, weights=xweights, color='lightblue', alpha=0.5)
ax.hist(y, weights=yweights, color='salmon', alpha=0.5)

ax.set(title='Histogram Comparison', ylabel='% of Dataset in Bin')
ax.margins(0.05)
ax.set_ylim(bottom=0)
plt.show()
```

[image]

On the other hand, what you're currently doing (`weights` and `normed`) would result in (note the units on the y-axis):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)

x = np.random.normal(5, 2, 10000)
y = np.random.normal(2, 1, 3000000)

xweights = 100 * np.ones_like(x) / x.size
yweights = 100 * np.ones_like(y) / y.size

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hist(x, weights=xweights, color='lightblue', alpha=0.5, normed=True)
ax.hist(y, weights=yweights, color='salmon', alpha=0.5, normed=True)

ax.set(title='Histogram Comparison', ylabel='% of Dataset in Bin')
ax.margins(0.05)
ax.set_ylim(bottom=0)
plt.show()
```

[image]